# Uncaught TypeError with snake robot

Tags: javascript, html

Alright guys, I'm having the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
```

When using this code

```
var y=document.getElementsByClassName('snake-snakebody-block          snake-snakebody-alive  snake-snakebody-alive')
//console.log(y.style)
console.log(y.style.left)
console.log(y.style.top)
```

on this element

```
<div class="snake-snakebody-block          snake-snakebody-alive  snake-snakebody-alive" style="left: 40px; top: 580px; width: 20px; height: 20px; z-index: 5;"></div>
```

And I'm at a loss. how can I fix

Comment: What's the reason for assigning the class `snake-snakebody-alive` twice to the same element?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 0):

Because getElementsByClassName returns a list of elements you have to take the first element from array like this:

`console.log(y[0].style.left)`